# why should we specify https in forms or href instead of directly specificing the domain name

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
  <form action="https://www.wikipedia.org/" method = 'post'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username"> 
        <input type="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit">
        <button>submdit</button>
    </form>
```

why should we use https before specifying the domain name?

Comment: Because that is how the [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) works if you have a domain name in the uri. It is called the protocol and it can be http, https (and other not relevant types)

Answer (score 1):

[The form action tag must be an url](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-fs-action), and the first part of an url begins with the protocol, so there isn't much to say.

The "protocol" part is called scheme in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-42), which is the standard that defines this urls.

In a nutshell:you have to put https because to comply with a lot of standards.

Comment: I don't see any mention of a "default protocol" in the (very long!) spec. When I tried, `action="www.wikipedia.org"` gets treated as a relative URL, so will post to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832577/www.wikipedia.org`

Comment: Ok, I will change the post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a website hosted at `http://nick.com` and a Python CGI script on your server to process the POST requests called `nic.py`. As you are planning to migrate your entire site to `https://nick.com.au` in future, you decide to provide a relative link to your CGI script, saving you the need to hardcode the base URL:

`<form action="nic.py" method = 'post'>`

This works. When users submit the form, they will be sent to either `http://nick.com/nic.py` or `https://nick.com.au/nic.py`, depending on the base URL.

But imagine what would happen if the standard tried to recognise domain names. `.py` is the top level domain for Paraguay, so the link would send them to [nic.py](http://nic.py) instead, which is probably not what you intended.

(On a side note, the WHATWG URL spec allows a [scheme-relative URL](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-relative-url-string), like `//nic.py`, which will go to either `http://nic.py` or `https://nic.py` depending on whether or not the base URL of your site was `http` or `https`)